# How to post data to different model in Django restframework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am new to restframework .I am trying to save my post data to a different model. I have no idea how to do it or if is it possible.

views.py

```
class AllAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        task = Task.objects.all()
        taskserializer = TaskSerializer(task, many=True)
        event = Event.objects.all()
        eventserializer = EventSerializer(event, many=True)
        context = [taskserializer.data,eventserializer.data]
        return Response(context)
    
    def post(self,request):
        taskserializer = TaskSerializer(data = request.data)
        eventserializer = EventSerializer(data = request.data)
        if taskserializer.is_valid():
            taskserializer.save()

            return Response(taskserializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        if eventserializer.is_valid():
            eventserializer.save()

            return Response(taskserializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I am trying to do this in a single path, how can I differentiate my data while request?

I tried by putting 2 serializers into the post function but it only save to the 1st serializer

Comment: single path mean single function ?

Comment: in the same url for this APIView the path that we set in urls.py

Comment: can i know your actual requirement what you intend to do? logical part